# How to integrate calendar plugin in IPhone using cordova and phonegap app

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am working on a phonegap app for IPhone using cordova. I am trying to implement a scenario where I need to open the IPhone native calendar when the user clicks on a particular button to add an event. I have followed [this link](https://github.com/felixactv8/Phonegap-Calendar-Plugin-ios) to  accomplish my task, i.e, Calendar Plugin for IPhone.

I did the following steps as they specified:

1. Added CalendarPlugin.m,CalendarPlugin.h in the Plugins folder
2. Added calendar.js file and add refrence in my .html file.
3. Added dependencies EventKit framework and the EventKitUI framework
4. Added the plugin with the key/pair value of calendarPlugin in
   cordova.plist file.

And my HTML file would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
  <title>My Calendar Plugin</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

<script src="assets/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/Scripts/cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/Scripts/calendar.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/Scripts/index.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function addEvent()
{
var cal = new calendarPlugin();
console.log("creating event");
var title= "My Sample Appt";
var location = "Los Angeles";
var notes = "This is a sample note";
var startDate = "2012-04-16 09:30:00";
var endDate = "2012-04-16 12:30:00";
var errCall = function(theerror) {
 console.log("Error occurred - " + theerror);
 }
var succCall = function(themessage) {
console.log("Success - " + themessage);
 }
cal.createEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate, succCall, errCall);
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="btnAddEvent" onclick="return addEvent();"/>

</body>
</html>
```

But I am unable to open the native calendar and add an event at a specified date. I have reviewed several StackOverflow questions and Google Groups discussions, but they have not worked for me. I have changed my calendarPlugin.m and calendarPlugin.h files according to IPhone 6 updates specified in the issues section of github. Please guide me if I went a wrong direction in implementing calendarplugin in phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cal = window.plugins.calendarPlugin
```

instead of,

```
cal = new calendarPlugin()
```

See if that helps.